# random_randint does not work with merge sort

Tags: python, python-3.x

Merge sort using some random numbers is not working. I get `None` as the output on the terminal when I call `merge_sort()` to sort the random numbers. Any ideas?

Output: 
Random Numbers?:
20
Merge Sort: [7, 7, 10, 19, 10, 1, 3, 6, 15, 10, 15, 5, 0, 1, 6, 9, 15, 1, 5, 6]
**None**

```
def merge_sort(sequence):
    if len(sequence) > 1:
        half_sequence = len(sequence) // 2
        first_half = sequence[:half_sequence]
        second_half = sequence[half_sequence:]

        merge_sort(first_half)
        merge_sort(second_half)
        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0

        while i < len(first_half) and j < len(second_half):
            if first_half[i] < second_half[j]:
                sequence[k] = first_half[i]
                i += 1
                #print (i)
            else: 
                sequence[k] = second_half[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1
            #print (i)

        while i < len(first_half):

            sequence[k] = first_half[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(second_half):
            sequence[k] = second_half[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

def random_list(n):
    lista = [0] * n
    for i in range(n):
          lista[i] = random.randint(0,n)
    return lista

print("Random Numbers?:")
n=int(input())

random_num = random_list(n)
print ("Merge Sort: {}".format(random_num))
print(merge_sort(random_num))´´´
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `merge_sort` function does not have a `return` statement

Answer (score 0):

```
    import random
    def merge_sort(sequence):
        if len(sequence) > 1:
            half_sequence = len(sequence) // 2
            first_half = sequence[:half_sequence]
            second_half = sequence[half_sequence:]

            merge_sort(first_half)
            merge_sort(second_half)
            i = 0
            j = 0
            k = 0

            while i < len(first_half) and j < len(second_half):
                if first_half[i] < second_half[j]:
                    sequence[k] = first_half[i]
                    i += 1
                    #print (i)
                else: 
                    sequence[k] = second_half[j]
                    j += 1
                k += 1
                #print (i)

            while i < len(first_half):

                sequence[k] = first_half[i]
                i += 1
                k += 1

            while j < len(second_half):
                sequence[k] = second_half[j]
                j += 1
                k += 1
        return sequence

        def random_list(n):
            lista = [0] * n
            for i in range(n):
                  lista[i] = random.randint(0,n)
            return lista

        print("Random Numbers?:")
        n=int(input())

        random_num = random_list(n)
        print ("Merge Sort: {}".format(random_num))
        print(merge_sort(random_num))´´´
```

Your merge sort function doesn't have a return statement. Please return `sequence`.